# Your identity could not be authenticated error received from web service when try through run window application

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, wcf-security

I am working on window service where I need to call web service which uses x509 certificate type security to authenticate.

Now I have .cer file generated on my system by importing .pfx and .crt file then exported .cer file. Which I am using in VS2015 to communicate with web service.

Its working fine. Then If I create setup and install on same system but giving error below. Its error returned by web service

```
"error_name" : "authentication_failure",
    "error_advice" : "Your identity could not be authenticated. This may mean that your request was not accompanied with your Client Certificate, or your software does not have access to your Private Key in order to encrypt messages correctly. Please check your software's configuration and associated file permissions for both your Client Certificate and Private Key. In addition, please check that your software supports secure connections using TLS 1.2 or higher."
```

Earlier I was using code below to load .cer when I try to debug in visual studio and it is working fine

```
X509Certificate certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateFilePath"].ToString());
```

and In app.config

```
<add key="CertificateFilePath" value="E:\ZooplaCerts\test\zooplasandbox_cert.cer"/>
```

Now When I create setup and install and run window service I am getting above error

I have tried to change code to below

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateFilePath"].ToString(), string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

but still getting same error. Then I tried to change `Log On Type` from service and selected `Local System Account` but still same error

Error I am receiving when try to run window service by installing

```
"error_name" : "authentication_failure",
    "error_advice" : "Your identity could not be authenticated. This may mean that your request was not accompanied with your Client Certificate, or your software does not have access to your Private Key in order to encrypt messages correctly. Please check your software's configuration and associated file permissions for both your Client Certificate and Private Key. In addition, please check that your software supports secure connections using TLS 1.2 or higher."
```

Comment: Please don't ask questions saying "why do I get a NullReferenceException", especially in this case where the error is clearly being thrown in your code, as indicated by the first line of the traceback.  The answer is always because something is null and you didn't check for it before attempting to use the null value.  Do some debugging and find out what is null when you run your code as a service. Your question really should be 'why is XYZ null when I run my program as a service'?

Comment: You cannot draw a conclusion that “which apparently because of window service can't access that file” yet. Debug the app first, so see which reference is null, and then drill down further. A service app runs completely different a normal app, so debug carefully before guessing the cause.

Comment: @LexLi   how can i debug the service in visual studio as service? because as i mentioned if i try to run through code everything is working and I have seen on net that there is .cer file restriction when access through window service

Comment: Why cannot you ask Google? Articles like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx can be easily found.

Comment: @LexLi I have debug code as service and found error.. its not loading of .cer file.. its error that returned by web service through its is related to that. I have updated exact error in my question.

Comment: The service will be running under another user normally `Local Service` account, this might not have access to the cert :)

Comment: @KevinSmith then how do i solve this ?

Comment: You debug at a too shallow level, and without tracing such as WCF tracing or System.NET tracing, the cause won't show itself. Who has access to the private key of this certificate?

Comment: Try just running the service under your own user to see if it's a permissions, maybe you have something in your local cert store for your user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got everything working now When I tried to create a new .cer file from .pfx for local system account and set window service log on option as local system